# Allocate unallocated space to ubuntu partition (windows dualboot)

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, ram

I dual-booted Windows with Ubuntu (Ubuntu became the second partition). Now I want to transition to a single-boot system with Ubuntu. I have removed the Windows partition and turned it into unallocated data, but the Ubuntu cannot "retrieve/get" the unallocated data because its before the OS installation.

Here is an image of the Gpartion: https://i.imgur.com/wdl7DOF.png

[image]

How can I get the unallocated space into the Ubuntu partition?

Comment: You can use GParted to resize your partition. The process is described in the answer to this question.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions It will take some time to do this because all the files in your installation will be moved.

Answer (score 3):

Ensure all data is backed up.

Boot the computer to a live USB.

(You have to do this because the procedure will only work if the nvme0n1p5 partition is not mounted. In the image you provided in the question, it is mounted as shown by the little icon next to the partition name on the left.)

Once in the live session, in gparted:

Click the nvme0n1p5 partition, right-click and select Resize/Move. A box will pop up showing the partition. Drag its left boundary all the way to the left, then click Resize at the bottom.

Comment: You must boot from a Live USB or your install medium (in "Try Ubuntu" mode). One cannot manipulate a disk's partitions while any of the disk's partitions is mounted.

Comment: @waltinator you are right. I didn't recognize the little icons in this version of gparted. in mine they look like keys. I fixed the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Make the unallocated space "allocated".  In G-parted Just click on it.Go to the menu (partition in the menu-bar), and unmount (if necessary) the unallocated .  Then format the unallocated to  ext3 or 4.  Mount if afterwards. (with the menu of gparted). Just let the new partition as it is, its always safer to have two partitions on a disk, and you can you use the space in ubuntu (your data for ex.)